# Python / Pygame - write pygame display with multiple primatives to a single image file

Tags: python, pygame

I have created a surface with many primitive objects drawn on my surface as in the example code. I want to save the display as an single image file, instead of drawing the surface every time.

```
  import pygame, sys, time, os
  from pygame.locals import *


  pygame.init()

  winheight = 1000
  winlegth = 1200

  winsurface = pygame.display.set_mode((winlegth,winheight), 0, 32)

  go = pygame.image.load('start.png')

  clock = pygame.time.Clock()

  # run the game loop
  while True:

       # check for the QUIT event
      for event in pygame.event.get():
             if event.type == QUIT:
             pygame.quit()
             sys.exit()

    #top left corner
      pygame.draw.rect(winsurface, (0,128,0),(0,0,200,200))
      winsurface.blit(go,(0,0))

   # many more objects blit to the screen
   ...
```

Comment: Check the documentation: http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html pygame.image.save() is what you need

Answer (score 1):

Actually really simple to save a drawn pygame surface with too many primitives.

```
pygame.image.save(background,'image.png')
```